# Imagesc ButtonDownFcn problems in MATLAB, using custom toolbar action

Tags: matlab, toolbar, matlab-guide

I'm trying to use the `ButtonDownFcn` on an `imagesc` figure in MATLAB. I want to enable this function by clicking on a custom button I have created on the toolbar.

The `ButtonDownFcn` will call methods that will cause it to return the position of the pixel selected using the `ButtonDownFcn`, so that I can graph how that pixel changes through time.

NOTES: 

- I am using GUIDE in matlab

- `imagesc` is plotting a 3D matrix. I already have implemented code that allows me to travel through how the image changes through time, using a button created in GUIDE.

What I am struggling with, at the moment, is the `ButtonDownFcn` of the `imagesc`. I've read over and over on how to do this (through research on the internet), but I can't seem to get it to work.

Any help is appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
    % --------------------------------------------------------------------
function ui_throughTime_ClickedCallback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to ui_throughTime (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
valS = get(handles.txt_zaxis,'string');
display(valS);
val = str2num(valS);
d = handles.data;
m = imagesc(d(:,:,val),'parent',handles.axis, 'HitTest', 'off','buttondownfcn',{@getPlace, handles});
set(handles.axis,'buttondownfcn',{@getPlace, handles,m});

function getPlace(hObject,handles,event_obj,place)
% data = randn(120,160); 
% ax = axes;
% imagesc(data,);
if (gcf == place)
    pause(1); 
    cursor = get(handles.axis,'CurrentPoint'); % get point
    % Get X and Y from point last clicked on the axes 
    x = (cursor(1,1));
    y = (cursor(1,2));
    disp(['x = ' num2str(x) ' y = ' num2str(y)]); 
end
```

Comment: Why have you set the `'HitTest'` (*selectability*) of the image to `'Off'`? Just try `imagesc(d(:,:,val),'parent',handles.axis,'ButtonDownFcn',{@getPlace, handles});` and see if it works.

Comment: Because I had read that by turning HitTest off I'll be able to select that axis that the imagesc is formed on. Ill try turning it off now.

EDIT: I removed hittest and got this error: Error using `matrixexplorer>getPlace (line 467)
Not enough input arguments.
 
Error while evaluating image ButtonDownFcn`

Comment: There are (at least) 3 ways you can do that as mentioned in the answer below. The easiest may be the first one. Let me know if it's not clear.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example:

```
%% Init
fig_h = figure('CloseRequestFcn', 'run = 0; delete(fig_h);');
rgb = imread('peppers.png');
run = 1; t = 0;

%% Loop
while run
    t = t + 0.05;
    imagesc(rgb*sin(t), 'ButtonDownFcn', 'disp(''Clicked'')');
    pause(0.01);
end
```

Above the `'ButtonDownFcn'` of the image is being used so the `'HitTest'` property of the image must be `'On'`.

Below is the case that the `'ButtonDownFcn'` of the axes are used and since the image is in front of the axes, `'HitTest'` property of the image should be `'Off'` or the axes won't be selectable.

```
%% Loop
ax = axes;
while run
    t = t + 0.05;
    imagesc(rgb*sin(t), 'Parent', ax, 'HitTest', 'Off');
    set(ax, 'ButtonDownFcn', 'disp(''Clicked'')')
    pause(0.01);
end
```

It's also possible to use the figure `'ButtonDownFcn'` and again the image `'HitTest'` should be `'Off'`. However in this case clicked points of outside of the image ( or interested area) should be filtered programmatically.

Hope it helps.